# Spring Data / Neo4J Repository : findByXXX returns Map, not Entity

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using Spring Data Neo4J.

I have extended the basic `GraphRepository` interface, adding a method, as follows:

```
/**
 * Extension to the repository interface for standard Spring Data repo's that
 * perform operations on graph entities that have a related RDBMS entity.
 * 
 * @author martypitt
 *
 * @param <T>
 */
public interface RelatedEntityRepository<T> extends GraphRepository<T>, 
RelationshipOperationsRepository<T>,CypherDslRepository<T>  {
    public T findByEntityId(Long id);
}
```

However, I'm finding that subclasses of this interface don't behave as expected.

```
public interface UserRepository extends RelatedEntityRepository<UserNode>{
}
```

When I call `UserRepository.findByEntityId(1L)`, I expect to get a single instance of `UserNode` returned, or `null`.

Instead, I get a `scala.collection.JavaConversions$MapWrapper`.

However, if I change the `UserRepository` to specify the type, then everything works (though, defeats the purpose of the baseclass)

```
public interface UserRepository extends RelatedEntityRepository<UserNode>{
    public UserNode findByEntityId(Long id);
}
```

Here's a test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"/graph-test-context.xml"})
@Transactional
public class UserRepositoryTests {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    // For Bug
    @Test
    public void canFindByEntityId()
    {
        UserNode userNode = new UserNode(1L);
        userRepository.save(userNode);

        UserNode node = userRepository.findByEntityId(1L);
        assertThat(node, notNullValue());
        assertThat(node, isA(UserNode.class));
    }
}
```

Running this test with the extra line in UserRepository commented out fails.  Otherwsie, the test passes.

Is this a bug?  Have I written the repo interface correctly?

Comment: Seems like the repository method is returning a *Result* object instead of the proper class object. You could try to convert the object returned by the *findByEntityId* method passing it to the *convert* method of the *Neo4jOperations* class: `UserNode node = neo4jOperations.convert(userRepository.findByEntityId(1L), UserNode.class);`

Answer (score 0):

remigio is right, it returns a wrapped object which you'll have to convert.

However, this won't be possible using a common baseclass for different entity types.

Here's why:

You'd think creating a wrapper class for the query result annotated with `@MapResult` should work, eg.

```
@MapResult
public interface ResultMap<T> {
    @ResultColumn("usernode") <T> getNode();
}
```

And use it like this in your repository class:

```
ResultMap<T> findByEntityId(Long id);
```

And like this in your test:

```
ReultMap<UserNode> = userRepository.findByEntityId(1L);
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work, for two reasons:

- The repository returns a `NodeProxy` class inside the map instead of a UserNode
- @ResultColumn annotation has to be configured with a column name, which seems to be automatically generated in the result based on the type of class, "usernode" in your case.

What does work is this then:

```
@MapResult
public interface ResultMap {
    @ResultColumn("usernode") NodeProxy getNode();
}

ResultMap rm = userRepository.findByEntityId(1L);
NodeProxy proxy = rm.getNode();
UserNode userNode = template.convert(proxy, UserNode.class);
```

`template` is AutoWired like this:

```
@Autowired Neo4jOperations template;
```

Unfortunately that doesn't really work either, due to point 2 above :(